# onclick not getting called after activity finished with finishAfterTransition

Tags: android, onclick, onbackpressed

Activity User goes to Activity **B** from **A** onclicking ***launchB*** in A
again, hits the back button on & goes to **A**. 
Now **A** 's same button's onclick is not getting called in this case & other buttons click is getting called, except this ***launchB***!, which is strange.
I'm looking for smooth experience.

Activity **B** onBackPressed:

```
    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

    for (int i = 0; i < rowContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {

            View rowView = rowContainer.getChildAt(i);
                    rowView.animate()
                            .setStartDelay(i * SCALE_DELAY)
                            .scaleX(0).scaleY(0)
                            .setListener(new AnimatorAdapter() {

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

                                    @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                        activity.finishAfterTransition();
                                    }
                                }

                            });

}

        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);

       return;
        }
```

Am I missing something?

**launchB** onclick():

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.DATA, getData());
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in, R.anim.out);
```

Comment: Post your A button's onClick code

Answer (score 0):

Usually in android the method onBackpressed should not be overrirded because in backPress is handled by android system itself.Removing of activities, poping fraagments from bacstack on backpress is handler by android system itself.Remove the code   activity.finishAfterTransition() and call super method to remove the second activity.

Change your code like this

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);

    for (int i = 0; i < rowContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View rowView = rowContainer.getChildAt(i);
        rowView.animate()
                .setStartDelay(i * SCALE_DELAY)
                .scaleX(0).scaleY(0)
                .setListener(new AnimatorAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        }

                    });

                }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**:
The activity overridePendingTransition() doesnot give desired result when used inside onBackPress.Instead you have to add the code inside onfinish of activity B.

```
 @Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);

    for (int i = 0; i < rowContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View rowView = rowContainer.getChildAt(i);
        rowView.animate()
                .setStartDelay(i * SCALE_DELAY)
                .scaleX(0).scaleY(0)
                .setListener(new AnimatorAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd (Animator animation){
                            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        }

                    });
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, activity will be finished prior to those transition animation, which is not I'm looking for

Comment: please check the updated code..I tried transition is not smooth since my linearlayout has multiple childs & activity finished abruptly.

Comment: what are you doing in that loop?

Comment: I was trying to achieve transition on childs of linearlayout( rowContainer) starting from top to bottom way.

Comment: it didn't work.. onclick is not detecting this is the main problem.

Comment: Actual scenario is A has drawer and on click of item of drawer B is opening, but after coming back to A, B is not getting called. Rest activities of other items of menu works fine since they're not having transition & finish code like this case. I can't post the code since it is long but code is same. It has onMenuClicked() method in place of onclick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155237/discussion-between-askq-and-anonymous).